# I am facing issues while creating a IOS Build in Nativescript environment "Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, build, nativescript

I am facing issues while creating my ios build in the native script environment. This error is in nsld.sh file which is the ios platform file.

I removed the ios platform multiple times and add the platform again but still the same issue every time.

Here is my error:

/Users/mypc/Code/app/MobileApp/mobileApp_nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/nsld.sh: line 60: /Users/mypc/Downloads/Xcode: No such file or directory
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: it seems that xcode is not installed. you can run "ns doctor" to confirm nativescript status.

Comment: Xcode is installed properly and I also tried ns doctor command but no issue was found.